# ASP.NET Core Web application 403 error after deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I create an ASP.NET Core Web application(.NET Core 3.1) sample project, and I can run it in localhost.

I install dotnet sdk(dotnet --version 3.1.422) and runtime on DigitalOcean Droplet VPS(Ubuntu 20.04, [link](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/plesk)) and publish it to VPS, but I got 403 error on every page.

I can browse static files like https://mydomain/wwwroot/css/site.css, but another path like / or /privacy only shows 403 errors. How can I fix it? Tks.

My publish option in VS2022:

- publish type: folder
- target framework: netcoreapp 3.1
- deployment mode: framework-dependent/self-contained both tried
- target runtime: portable

I zip the files in bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish and upload them via Plesk file manager.

[image]

---

I use `cd /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/` and `dotnet run`

Then I got an error message:

> Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs, or pass the path to the project using --project.

---

I use `cd /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/` and `dotnet WebApplication3.dll`

But it still shows 403 when I browse https://mydomain

> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Hosting environment: Production
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Content root path:/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs

Comment: did you try running `dotnet run` on your host? Without it the application will do nothing. That step is missing in your list of actions taken

Comment: There are many tutorials you can find from search engines like https://driesdeboosere.dev/blog/how-to-deploy-aspnet-core-31-app-to-digital-ocean-linux-droplet/#deploy-our-asp.net-core-3.1-app-to-ubuntu So give them a try and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edit some error message in my post, is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I install [Plesk .NET Toolkit](https://www.plesk.com/extensions/dot-net/) then setting the sample site like this below.

[image]

It works! The website runs but I still don't know how to setting the same thing via terminal...